# Access outer loop count variable inside inner loop in python

Tags: python-3.x

below is the sample code, want count variable to be access from inner loop. count variable is incremented in outer loop. count value always 3 even though increment in outer loop. here list2 is list of lists. list1 is normal list.

```
    list1 = ['element1', 'element2', 'element3', 'elements4']
    list2 = [[ABC,24-2-2016,0,1,0,0.1], [ABC,24-2-2016,0,1,0,0.1]]
    count=3
    for element in list1:
        print(element)
        for r in list2:
            print(r[count])
        count+=1
```

In details, want to fetch data from a db table which is like below

existng table: all these rows fetched into list2

```
context   date       element1 element2 element3 element4
ABC       24-2-2016    0        1        0       0.1
ABC       24-2-2016    0        2        0       0.2
ABC       24-2-2016    0        1        0       0.1
XYX       24-2-2016    1        0        0       0.1
XYX       24-2-2016    0        1        0       0.1
```

above table has to be transformed like below

new table:

```
context   date       elementname   elementvalue
ABC       24-2-2016   element1      0
ABC       24-2-2016   element1      0
ABC       24-2-2016   element1      0
ABC       24-2-2016   element1      1
ABC       24-2-2016   element1      0
ABC       24-2-2016   element2      1
ABC       24-2-2016   element2      2
ABC       24-2-2016   element2      1
ABC       24-2-2016   element2      0
ABC       24-2-2016   element2      1
ABC       24-2-2016   element3      0
ABC       24-2-2016   element3      0
ABC       24-2-2016   element3      0
ABC       24-2-2016   element3      0
ABC       24-2-2016   element3      0

...etc
```

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing with this code? What are the contents of `list1` and `list2`? For the first iteration of outer loop `count` will remain 3 irrespective of the iteration of inner loop

Comment: count values always 3(initialized value) even though incremented in outer loop. we can consider list1 and list2 any normal list

Comment: What does `insert` do? Unless it does something with `count` or `list1` is empty, this not reproducible. If `list1` is not empty, the value of `count` increases and r[count] references different elements of `r`.

Comment: consider list1 is columns list from DB table and list2 is a row from same DB table, insert inserts the data into some other table.

Comment: Does the `list1` contain more than 1 item? Can you show the contents of both list?

Comment: What is `insert`?

Comment: pls check description, updated it

Comment: Your code should be executable for us. For debugging purposes, you could change it to `print`

Comment: Shouldn't there be a XYX in the first column of some rows in the last table that you have posted (always the last two rows for a specific element)

Answer (score 0):

When I execute your code, then the value does not stay at 3, but increases until it is out of range. You will need to make sure that the outer loop goes through your columns element1..4 (the items in `list1`) and, at the same time, goes through values 2..5 (to acces the correct items in `r`). You can use a ranged based for loop like this for this. I also made some minor fixes in the list creation and changed one of the dates to make the two entries more distinguishable. This code works as you intent:

```
list1 = ['element1', 'element2', 'element3', 'elements4']
list2 = [["ABC","24-2-2016",0,1,0,0.1], ["ABC","25-2-2016",0,1,0,0.1]]

for i in range(len(list1)):
    elem=list1[i]
    print(elem)
    column=i+2
    for r in list2:
        print(r[0], r[1],elem, r[column])
    column+=1
```

Output:

```
element1
ABC 24-2-2016 element1 0
ABC 25-2-2016 element1 0
element2
ABC 24-2-2016 element2 1
ABC 25-2-2016 element2 1
element3
ABC 24-2-2016 element3 0
ABC 25-2-2016 element3 0
elements4
ABC 24-2-2016 elements4 0.1
ABC 25-2-2016 elements4 0.1
```

What you are trying to do manually can be done with pandas `melt` function like this

```
testdata="""context   date       element1 element2 element3 element4
ABC       24-2-2016    0        1        0       0.1
ABC       24-2-2016    0        2        0       0.2
ABC       24-2-2016    0        1        0       0.1
XYX       24-2-2016    1        0        0       0.1
XYX       24-2-2016    0        1        0       0.1
"""
import io

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(testdata), sep="\s+")
df.melt(id_vars=["context", "date"], var_name="elementname", value_name="elementvalue")
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: inside inner loop count value is remains same i.e 2,

Comment: That's the idea. It produces the same result, just in a different order. Or was your intended results strictly order dependent?

Comment: yes, its order dependent

Comment: I have corrected the code. It produces the output in the order that you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ['element1', 'element2', 'element3', 'element4']
list2 = [['ABC','24-2-2016',0,1,0,0.1], ['ABC','24-2-2016',0,1,0,0.1]]
for r in list2:
    for idx,element in enumerate(list1):
        print(r[0], r[1], element, r[idx+2])
```

A small adjustment using `enumerate` helps get an index for use in `list2`'s sub-lists.

Comment: still idx value in inner loop is 2 not incrementing.

Comment: @Hmm Put it on the wrong loop. Updated